# Disable ProGuard in a specific variant

Tags: android, gradle

My project has 3 flavors and 2 build types:

```
productFlavors {
    dev1
    dev2
    production
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
    }
}
```

ProGuard is currently enabled in all 6 variants. I would like to disable ProGuard only in `dev1Debug` to speedup builds during development. Is there any way to do it?

I don't want to create an additional build type like `debugWithoutProguard` because some of the new variants will be redundant and there are some `debug`-only dependencies, java code and resources which will have to be shared between `debug` and `debugWithoutProguard`.